# Python Dataframe: Drop Rows if Column Contains Value From List --> Value TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a Python dataframe and I want to delete rows that contain values 4888 through 4893 in the AIRCRAFT field.  The aircraft field in the data frame are strings.

Below is the code I used:

```
aircraft_CS = list(range(4888, 4893))

df_adhoc_1_final = df_adhoc_1_final[~df_adhoc_1_final['AIRCRAFT'].isin([aircraft_CS])]
```

But below is the error I get: 
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: I'm not familiar with dataframes, but it looks like you've put a list in a list. Maybe just `.isin(aircraft_CS)`, rather than `.isin([aircraft_CS])`?

Comment: `isin` takes a list of scalars. You've passed it a nested list. Get rid of the `[..]`.